# jQuery AJAX not receiving response from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have an Ajax post call that calls to the doPost of my Java servlet correctly, but it doesn't seem to send a response. I have this script called within my HTML:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit2').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "GrooveAPICall",
                    data: { hiddenField: location.pathname, name: $('#name').val(), email: $('#email').val() },
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });            
        });
```

Then I have my servlet creating a response:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/html");
if (ticketResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= 200 && ticketResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 300) {
    out.print("worked");
} else {
    out.print("didn't work");
}
out.close();
```

Yet nothing is shown in the alert dialog. How can I get those statements to be printed? Is it due to the fact that AJAX does asynchronous calls so all these things happen at once?

Comment: Add an error handler to the Ajax call

Comment: Try using developer tools or fiddler to see the network traffic.  If in Chrome F12 and click on the network tab.

Comment: No error seems to be occurring. When I take a look at the network tab, and click on the GrooveAPICall (my servlet call) it shows the response 'didn't work'. I just need to get it shown somewhere on screen as an alert dialog or something.

Comment: Add dataType to the Ajax call